# I can't boot from USB on my Asrock Steel Legend X570

Tags: usb, bios, uefi, nvme

I recently replaced my NVMe on my system. Before I replaced the NVMe, I used Windows Media Installer to create a bootable USB stick. Everything went perfectly. After I finished replacing NVMe, my BIOS won't detect the USB stick. I can confirm the USB works because I got it working on another PC.

My BIOS is in UEFI mode, I have Secure Boot enabled along with CSM. I know that the NVMe I installed is also working because it was detected by my BIOS.

I'm baffled.

I've also plugged the USB into multiple different ports, USB 3.2 and 3. I don't have any USB 2 ports on my motherboard.

Comment: *... along with CSM* for starters, that's a mistake. Start by disabling CSM (AKA Legacy AKA "BIOS" mode, something you definitely don't need, don't want and not even works with Windows 11).

Comment: @ChanganAuto, now that's interesting because if I disable, my boot drive selection disappears. I'm pretty sure the one drive is in GPT format, which should make it appear, right?

Comment: GPT is required for **installing** any Windows in UEFI mode (as it should be since ~2012). It has nothing to do with booting external media. You should try the one-time boot menu (AKA Boot override) and if the USB doesn't appear in the list, keep it connected, reboot and try again.

Comment: I've tried that sadly. @ChanganAuto

Comment: If so re-do the USB - chances are it's somehow corrupt now -, try a different one... But whatever you do 1. avoid 1. CSM and 2. Don't format the new drive. That said what you need to figure out right now is how to boot the installer, a properly made one.

Comment: Yeah I guess so, it's just odd that it works perfectly fine on another system which uses UEFI. I mean, I'd consider it properly made. I used the Windows Installation Media executable. I could always download the ISO and use Rufus on it but, we'll see. I appreciate the help.